Use of matrix DBF table in QGIS
I have a shapefile with 3 fields. (For example fields A,B and C). Fields A and B are filled with data in the shapefile, field C is virtual. Next to it I have a dbf table. In the rows I have A values, in the columns I have B values and each combination of row and column has unique value in the body of the table.(This is the data for column C). Is there a way how to automatically get data from DBF table to my virtual field C in my shapefile?
I know it should be possible to do "manually" with expression using WHEN, AND, THEN for each row, but it is a lot of data to do it this way.
